# Similar products to MS EMET

Tags: windows, exploit, tools, detection, defense

Following the weekend announcement from Microsoft regarding the vulnerability in IE I have been looking at additional security defences for our endpoints. I've read some technical documentation and articles on the implementation of Microsoft's Enhanced Mitigation Toolkit. The product functionality looks like it could be a good addition to our existing defences (if configured and tested properly) but my only reservation is that there is no central management tool for the product. It'd be ideal to have a central console where I can see devices with the product installed and view reports where potential attacks have taken place.

Does anyone use a similar product within their environment? If so, which products?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It can be centrally managed of a sort from Group Policy.

Comment: Invincea has a comparison to EMET -- http://www.invincea.com/why-invincea/microsoft-emet-comparison/

Answer (score 0):

Newer anti-malware software can include some sort of 'process behavioral analysis' that performs similarly to EMET. Most enterprise AV solutions are centrally managed. Results may vary...

This is a vendor-neutral site, so I won't go into specific vendor offerings. Check out your favorite AV vendor and see what options they provide.